# drcsim simulator

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi
In the simulator that is published with the Drc robot is their a way to untie the robot from mid air?

thanks
Nachum

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/160/drcsim-simulator/) by [Nachum](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/50/nachum/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2012-11-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2012-11-14**:
The title to this question as well should probably be updated to something like: "Possible to unpin DRC robot?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/141/removing-pinning-from-the-hip-joint/

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0